# Scala and Ebean: Storing Sets as model fields

Tags: scala, playframework, ebean

If I define a model like so;

```
@Entity
case class User(name: String, age: Int) extends Model {
    …
    @Lob
    images: Set[String] = Set()
    …
}
```

I see that the `images` field doesn't get persisted: or at least in my test case with an in-memory database, it always gets set to `null` on retrieving the object.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some confusion.  @Lob is for "Large objects" so an image file (singlular) and not for a Set of String. Perhaps you are trying to store a 'Clob' but then that would be a single String (and not a set of String).

In Ebean from 4.3.1 you can use @Lob File imageFile; and then Ebean will stream the file in and out for you (into the temp dir for streaming out) and from there you can move the file, process it etc. Prior to 4.3.1  you had to use @Lob byte[] imageFile; (or for clob ...  @Lob String largeContent;) and if you wanted streaming roll it yourself (just like JPA currently) which is either more pain or more memory consumption.

So in 4.3.1 I'd recommend (because streaming large content is generally good):

```
@Entity
case class User(name: String, age: Int) extends Model {
    …
    @Lob
    imageFile: File 
    …
}
```